# Lumen: Method handle does not exist with jwt-auth, done the middleware

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, lumen

Hey so I just updated to Lumen 5.2 and ran into problems with jwt-auth. I have followed all instructions and updated my app.php file, including all middleware. I also composer required illuminate/routing and illuminate/auth.
However I get the error :

`BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method handle does not exist. in Macroable.php line 81 at ResponseFactory->__call('handle', array(object(Request), object(Closure)))`

I can't seem to get any sense out of that error?

Here is my boostrap/app.php for reference:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../'))->load();
} catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
    //
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
| that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
| application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
|
*/

//$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
//    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
//);

// For nested route groups to work
$app = new Fremail\NestedRouteGroups\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

 $app->withFacades();

$app->configure('jwt');
$app->configure('auth');

class_alias(Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class, 'JWTAuth');
class_alias(Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class, 'JWTFactory');


 $app->withEloquent();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Container Bindings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Now we will register a few bindings in the service container. We will
| register the exception handler and the console kernel. You may add
| your own bindings here if you like or you can make another file.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager::class,
    function ($app) {
        return $app->make('cache');
    }
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::class,
    function ($app) {
        return $app->make('auth');
    }
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory::class,
    Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory::class
);


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Middleware
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we will register the middleware with the application. These can
| be global middleware that run before and after each request into a
| route or middleware that'll be assigned to some specific routes.
|
*/

$app->middleware([
    Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory::class,
//     // Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
//     // Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
//     // Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
//    Laravel\Lumen\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
 ]);

// Middleware for authentication for the API
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth'        => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'jwt.auth'    => Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.refresh' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Service Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will register all of the application's service providers which
| are used to bind services into the container. Service providers are
| totally optional, so you are not required to uncomment this line.
|
*/

$app->register(App\Providers\GuardServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next we will include the routes file so that they can all be added to
| the application. This will provide all of the URLs the application
| can respond to, as well as the controllers that may handle them.
|
*/

$app->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($app) {
    require __DIR__.'/../app/Http/routes.php';
});

return $app;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: In Laravel, the method that is throwing that exception is attempting to dynamically handle calls to a class...can you confirm it's the same in Lumen? It would seem that something is calling `handle()` on a class, but the method doesn't exist in that class.

Comment: Yeah I think that's basically what's happening here too. Something is trying to call 'handle' on ResponseFactory but it does not exist. http://imgur.com/SIKYA52

Comment: can you show the offending code that is causing the error?

Comment: @Feek ended up just switching to Laravel. Bare errors just disappeared cheers tho 

Answer (score 4):

My answer must be late, but for future googlers, here is how I solved it (Lumen 5.3):

I've set the auth middleware in bootstrap/app.php:

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met the same mistakes as you.

But I made a mistake on the routing file.
I write routing files:

```
 $app->middleware(['auth'],function()use($app){
    $app->group(['prefix'=>'pur'],function()use($app){
        $app->get('list','PurchaseController@purList');
    });
});
```

This is wrong.
Routing should be defined first：

```
$app->group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () use ($app) {
$app->group(['prefix'=>'pur'],function()use($app){
    $app->get('list','PurchaseController@purList');
});
```

});

My wrong information：

[image]